# Need to replace SCNLight property caused changed target from iOS 10 to 9

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have to decrease target version from iOS 10 to 9. And one of my problems is how to appropriately replace this code :

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    target.light?.intensity = intensity
} else {
    // Replace 
}
```

What is similar to property intensity from SCNLight in older iOS versions?

Comment: Why would you want to lower your target version to iOS9? The percentage of iOS users being on iOS9 is really small, there's no point in supporting it anymore, especially if you've been targeting iOS10 until now. Moreover, I `intensity` seems to be an added property on `SCNLight`, I don't think there was an alternative to it previously.

Comment: It isn't my own decision. I have to. Maybe, is there similar function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've investigated this topic last time. I found the answer. Before SDK 10, you can set an intensity of white color

So:

```
target.light?.color = UIColor(white: intensity/1000.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

has effect the same as

```
target.light?.intensity = intensity
```

Problem is solved. Maybe someone in future will use my solve :)